# Why I am not able to change the state of my react component the second time and got no error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[image]

I have a currency dropdown menu when click appear and when click outside it disappears also when click on the same place it should disappears but when i am clicking on that button that function runs but the state does not change which is hiding that

```
//CurrencyDropwon.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { SelectWrapper,NavbarItem,CurrencyBtn } from "./CurrencyDropdownStyle";
import { getCurrency } from "../../../utls/MakeQuery";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { SelectInput } from '../../';
import { toggleCurrency } from '../../../store/reducers/currencyReducers'

export class CurrencyDropdown extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currency: [],
      isComponentVisible: true,
      isActiveCurrency:false,
      ref: React.createRef(null),
    };
  }

  handleHideDropdown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Escape') {
      this.setState({ isComponentVisible: false });
    }
  }

  handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (this.state.ref.current && !this.state.ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({
        isActiveCurrency:!this.state.isActiveCurrency
      })
      
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getCurrency()
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          currency: res.data.currencies,
        });
        this.props.toggleCurrency("USD+$");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

      document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleHideDropdown, true);
      document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true);
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleHideDropdown, true);
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true);
  }
  // Function That will handle the change of the currency in the state(●'◡'●)
  // Function that will show the currency selector
  
  
  render() {
    const handleCurrencyActive = () =>{
      console.log("handleCurrencyActive CLICKED");
      this.setState({
        isActiveCurrency:!this.state.isActiveCurrency
      })
    }
    
    return <>
          <NavbarItem>
              <CurrencyBtn onClick={()=>{handleCurrencyActive()}}>
                 {this.props.currencySymbol}    {this.state.isActiveCurrency ? "⮝":"⮟"}
              </CurrencyBtn>
                  {this.state.isActiveCurrency && <SelectWrapper ref={this.state.ref}>
                {this.state.currency ? this.state.currency.map((item,index)=>(
                        <SelectInput key={index} value={`${item.label}+${item.symbol}`} label={`${item.symbol} ${item.label}`}/>
                    )):""}
              </SelectWrapper> }
          </NavbarItem>

    </>;
  }
}
const  mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  return {
      currencyState:state.currency.currencyState,
      currencySymbol:state.currency.currencySymbol,
      cart:state.cart.cart.cartItems
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{toggleCurrency}) (CurrencyDropdown);
```

My Question:
Why I am facing this error the task is straight forward that the state should change and that dropwdown should hide

Comment: Are you sure `handleClickOutside = (event)` is not being triggered also when clicking inside the icon?
Maybe both `handleClickOutside = (event)` and `const handleCurrencyActive = ()` are being triggered at the same time.

Comment: you are right this is happeing how should i avoid it

Comment: @André yes this is what happeing i just coneole log both are getting triggered

Comment: Please write the answer so that i can accept it it is nice i just change the ref and it got fix

Comment: @sarangkkl how did you fix it?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava change `<NavbarItem>` to `<NavbarItem ref={this.state.ref}>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handleClickOutside = (event)` is being triggered also when clicking inside the icon.

When both `handleClickOutside = (event)` and `const handleCurrencyActive = ()` are being triggered at the same time you end up with the same initial state.

You can change the logic of `const handleCurrencyActive = ()` to only work when the dropdown is not visible. Since a touch in the icon is also a touch outside the dropdown menu `handleClickOutside = (event)` can handle close when you click a second time in the icon.

Answer (score 2):

```
    ref: React.createRef(null),
    };
  }

  flag = 0; //add this

  handleHideDropdown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Escape') {
```

...

```
handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (this.state.ref.current && !this.state.ref.current.contains(event.target) && this.flag === 0) {
      this.setState({
        isActiveCurrency:!this.state.isActiveCurrency
```

...

```
componentDidMount() {
      ...
      document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleHideDropdown, true);
      document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true);
      let IntervId = setInterval(this.resetFlag, 500); //add this
  }
```

...

```
resetFlag = () => {
    this.falg = 0;
  }
  
  render() {
    const handleCurrencyActive = () =>{
      this.flag = 1;
      console.log("handleCurrencyActive CLICKED");
      this.setState({
        isActiveCurrency:!this.state.isActiveCurrency
      })
    }
```

I hope this will be helpful for you.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Change your setState part like this when you want to use previous value of a state:

```
this.setState(pre => ({
        isActiveCurrency:!pre.isActiveCurrency
}))
```